# What is the probability in the following case?

Tags: probability

Given $100$ cells, each cell can contain the values $0$ or $1$ with

$0$ - with a probability of $0.96$

$1$ - with a probability of $0.04$

How can I calculate the probability of having at least one $1$ when $25$ cells are chosen from the $100$ cells?

Answer (score 0):

Is the total number of cells relevant at all? Assuming you choose the cells independently, the probability of having zero $1$s in the $25$ cells chosen is $P=(0.96)^{25}$, so the probability of having at least one $1$s is $1-P$.